# How to add a class to a tag in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

In select2 I am able to validate a tag when the user creates it via the [createTag](https://select2.org/tagging#customizing-tag-creation) option.

How can I add a class like `.text-danger` to tags that fail validation? For example:

```
$('#myselect').select2({
    createTag: function(term, data) {
      var value = term.term;
      if (validateEmail(value)) {
        return {
          id: value,
          text: value
        };
      }
      return {
          id: value,
          text: value,
          class: 'text-danger'   <------ NEW CLASS
      };
    }
```

});

Answer (score -1):

You can just add class to your target element example `#mySelect` if validation fails like this:

```
$('#myselect').select2({
createTag: function(term, data) {
  var value = term.term;
  if (validateEmail(value)) {
    return {
      id: value,
      text: value
    };
  }

  $('#myselect').addClass('text-danger');

  return {
      id: value,
      text: value
  };
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks but that does not add the class to the tag. It applies it to the entire input.

Comment: $($('#myselect').select2('container')).addClass('text-danger');

Comment: @LDS thanks but again that would just add the class to all tags. I only want to specify the created tag.

Comment: If you want to change the css for selected item then look the bellow link or wise in for loop can do theat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695034/select2-add-class-to-selected-option